# Set up Airflow for Multiple Environments

Tags: python, airflow

What's the idiomatic way to setup Airflow so if you have two environments, such as Production-East and Production-West, only the dags from each of these environments show up but they can live in a single repository?

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way to achieve this is with named queues.
Have multiple workers set up, some working on `Production-East` environment and some on `Production-West` environment. That way both DAGs show up in the UI but they execute only on the worker machines that have that specific environment on them.

From the [documentation for queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-ssl-connection-security):

When using the CeleryExecutor, the celery queues that tasks are sent to can be specified. queue is an attribute of BaseOperator, so any task can be assigned to any queue. The default queue for the environment is defined in the `airflow.cfg`’s `celery -> default_queue`. This defines the queue that tasks get assigned to when not specified, as well as which queue Airflow workers listen to when started.

Workers can listen to one or multiple queues of tasks. When a worker is started (using the command `airflow worker`), a set of comma delimited queue names can be specified (e.g. `airflow worker -q spark`). This worker will then only pick up tasks wired to the specified queue(s).

This can be useful if you need specialized workers, either from a resource perspective (for say very lightweight tasks where one worker could take thousands of tasks without a problem), or from an environment perspective (you want a worker running from within the Spark cluster itself because it needs a very specific environment and security rights).

Comment: The poster requested a solution wherein the processes for the environment only appear in the UI for said environment. Using a queue to segregate the items won't accomplish this.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, but this is actually very good advice.  I will probably implement the first answer as a temporary solution, and then set this as a longer term goal.

Comment: Perhaps we could combine these into a single response before I accept that takes this into account?  I would like to acknowledge the effort you put into this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have the files for each group put inside a subfolder and then set the `dags_folder` path to point to the appropriate subfolder for the server.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this answer, but also reference my comment below.